# OData (Wcf data service) to Swagger Generation

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, swagger, swashbuckle

May i know is it possible to convert OData (wcf data service) to swagger doc? i'm looking sample or convertor for this but i still missing for this. Odata is came from other party. Do i need to create the swagger by manual?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can get a [CSDL](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part3-csdl.html) document from the `$metadata` endpoint of the OData service and convert it to [OpenAPI](https://openapis.org/) (aka Swagger) using an [XSL style sheet](https://tools.oasis-open.org/version-control/browse/wsvn/odata/trunk/spec/examples/V4-CSDL-to-OpenAPI.xsl?sc=1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) and [Swashbuckle.OData](https://github.com/rbeauchamp/Swashbuckle.OData).